# How to search a word only in string literal in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to find all occurrences of a word that are part of a string literal in my c# solution. So I want to restrict my search to words in quoted sequences of characters.

For instance if I search for the word `magic`, the following line should **not** appear in the result :

```
string magic = "hello dad"
```

,and conversely, the following line should be found:

```
string test = "this is a magic line"
```

Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Can't you just use Wildcard search, eg. "/*magic/*" without the escape slashes, asterisks are italic in SO comments

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you have an array of strings and are searching for strings that contain the word? The data structure you're using matters!

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + F > Uncheck "Match Case" > Check "Match Whole Word" > Check "Use Regular Expressions" > Enter the following in Find what: 

".*magic.*" (include the quotes)

Comment: @Spluf in need to search in my code (via the VS IDE) - not by programming.

Comment: my bad, then you can use a regular expression for that in VS if you do ctrl + F or use @Ingenioushax solution

Comment: @Ingenioushax Thank you: it works. could you write it as an answer ?

Comment: the regex for magic would be (magic)+

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just moving this from comments to answer.

CTRL + SHIFT + F > Uncheck "Match Case" > Check "Match Whole Word" > Check "Use Regular Expressions" > Enter the following in Find what: ".*magic.*" (include the quotes)

Comment: To include other literals you may want to use `[\$@]?".*magic.*"`

Comment: I think this is not enough. I searched for `".*&.*"` and this came up:
`if (!SNetCreateGame("local", "local", "local", 0, (char *)&sgGameInitInfo.dwSeed, 8, 1, "local", "local", &unused)) {`. My understanding is that this line should not show in the results because it has no string literal with a `&` inside, as per OPs request.

Comment: And it doesn't work for multiline string literals, but may be "good enough".